# Is there a way to highlight roads using leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I have a complete set of waypoints (beginning, end, every intersection) and I'd like to display this on a map. I don't want to use a routing service and it should be offline.

How can I draw polylines on a map so that they follow the curves of the road?
I'm using leaflet.

Could the data be extracted from a relational database(PostgreSQL) and then convert it into GeoJSON and display on the map by leaflet?

I can't use any paid services either.

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet has a [`polyline`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline) object. MapBox has a nice [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/polyline/) how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think scai has given you a good example to practice.By the way you can also store the data in JSON format in PostgreSQL.Refer this documentation for more details.[JSON Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html)